# Calling a method from inside of another class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node class like this:

```
var Classes = function () {
};

Classes.prototype.methodOne = function () {
    //do something
};
```

when i want to call `methodOne`, i use this:

```
this. methodOne();
```

And it works. But right now i have to call it from inside of another method of another class. This time its not works and cant access to `methodOne` :

```
var mongoose = new Mongoose();
mongoose.save(function (err, coll) {
  //save to database
  this. methodOne(); //this does not work
}
```

how i can call methodOne? i use `Classes.methodOne()` but it's not work

Comment: this refers to mongoose Class

Comment: @wZVanG: yes but i want to access main class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` inside the `save` callback is in a **new context** and is a different `this` than the outside one. *Preserve* it in a variable where it has access to `methodOne`

```
var that = this;
mongoose.save(function (err, coll) {
  //save to database
  that.methodOne();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create variable outside of mongoose function.

```
var self = this;

var mongoose = new Mongoose();
mongoose.save(function (err, coll) {
  //save to database
  self.methodOne(); //If you call `this` from here, This will refer to `mongoose` class
}
```

If you are in an environment that works with ES6 you can use the **[Arrow expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**:

```
var mongoose = new Mongoose();
mongoose.save((err, col) => {
    //save to database
    this.methodOne();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is create an object of class Classes inside your other class and refer that method using this object: Ex:

```
var objClasses;
var mongoose = new Mongoose();
mongoose.save(function (err, coll) {
  //save to database
objClasses = new Classes();
  objClasses. methodOne(); //this should work
}
```

If it doesn't work please explain what exactly you want to achieve.